# Prestashop 1.7.x override javascript from module with my own module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am writing my own module that need to override ps_shoppingcart.js

I try to read in documentation:

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/overriding-modules/#overriding-templates-and-assets

```
└── modules
    ├── css
    │   ├── external-lib.css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── js
    │   └── app.js
```

I know that kind of override it is for themes, but I was hope that was working for modules too, and unfortunately I don't find nothing about module.

Another idea may be override Ps_Shoppingcart class and call my own javascript.

Do you any idea how to solve it or some doc link, tutorial etc.

**UPDATE** **Solved**

This is the solution that I found it, I am not sure if is the best way but it is work.

I override the ps_shoppingcart.php and then I try to load my own javascript.
That probably because path error, was not loaded, so I included it from my module and now it is work

ps_shoppingcart.php override I don't include any javascript

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}
class Ps_ShoppingcartOverride extends Ps_Shoppingcart
{
    public function hookHeader()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

If someone know better solution, I'd be happy to hear it

Thanks
Gabriele

Comment: Just to confirm , overrides are enable in your shop. Check once in your backoffice.

Comment: I already override Product class and that is work, so I think is enable

Comment: ok then one more check, can you check in view-page-source that your newjs file is included here or not? If yes, then open a file and check your updated code is placed here or not. Maybe some cache problem.

Comment: No is not included, just if I put in my hookHeader, but will be double

Comment: Now I override ps_shoppingcart.php and it is work, but is not include the js file from hookHeader, this is because maybe it is looking in shoppingcart module folder

Comment: I found an easy solution and solve it, I will update this post, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unregisterJavascript` FrontController function in your module hookHeader to delete some js instance and then register your own js to override its functionality.

This line in your case:

```
$this->context->controller->unregisterJavascript('modules-shoppingcart');
```

Now, you can register your

```
$this->context->controller->registerJavascript('instance-name', 'js-resource-path);
```